# Wordpress plugin - Should I use wp table prefix?

Tags: database, wordpress, database-design

I am developing a Wordpress plugin which uses a connection to the same database where the CMS is installed. The plugin aims to let the user create survey-like pages.

I understand tables used by my application should have a representative prefix to them so they can be easily identified in the database. (e.g., `survey_question`)

Knowing this, is it still good practice to include the installation table prefix to specify the application being part of Wordpress? (e.g., `wp_survey_question`)

I wouldn't care so much adding the installation prefix if this didn't threaten the readability of my SQL queries. For example:

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "survey_question
        INNER JOIN " . $wpdb->prefix . "survey_answer
    ... ";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a routine practice, mostly because the prefix is customizable during the WordPress installation phase, so the default prefix wp_ shouldn't work sometimes. Furthermore, the prefix changes in a multisite installation (it could be wp_2_, wp_6_, etc.)

Comment: So, because my application is dependent of the installation (different WP installations would have different lists of surveys) I should add the WP installation prefix to my tables?

Comment: Yes, always put the prefix. If there are more WP installations with the multisite enable you could get a conflict.